# MSSQL 2008: динамический запрос

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Добрый день!

Такая ситуация: имеются 3 хранимых процедуры (SP1, SP2, SP3). Они возвращают такие колонки:

```
SP1: a,b,c

SP2: d,e,

SP3: f,g,h
```

Выполняем ХП таким образом:

```
"EXEC " + <имя процедуры>
```

Имеется также таблица "Temp" с хардкордными колонками ("ID", "Value")

Пользователь вводит 2 имени колонок, которые он хочет получить после выполнения хранимки (не все колонки, а только 2)

**Нужно сделать вот что:**
Вне зависимости от того, какая процедура выполняется, организовать следующее: 
Из результата выполнения хранимки необходимо выбрать только те колонки, которые ввел пользователь и поместить их в таблицу Temp.

Помогите, пожалуйста, алгоритм решения найти.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не всё понятно, но предлагаю сделать Temp с 3-мя столбцами (по максимуму возвращаемых хп столбцов. Третий столбец должен иметь значение по умолчанию (NULL, например).
Тогда результат любой хп можно поместить в эту таблицу, а потом уже из нее выбирать то, что нужно пользователю.